# Sync between two projects/files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any extension available to sync two local projects in Visual Studio Code.

If it is there then how to configure.

Example we have a FileSync tool available in Sublime Text to sync between two local directories.
 Like Below.

```
{
  "mappings": [
    {
      "source": "D:/XXXX/XXX/hx5", 
      "destination": "C:/XXXX/XXX/hx5"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can use "Deploy" or "Deploy reloaded" extension for this.

Comment: Any details about these extensions?